# Calling method from another class objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

So far the remote wipe works, but I'm having trouble starting a backup in the background. The remote wipe also works in the background. I am trying to call the `startBackgroundBackupActivity` method from my `locationHandler` class which works in the background.

```
BackgroundBackupHandler.m

- (void) OnSyncComplete:(NSNumber*)result message:(NSString *)message{
    NSLog(@"-(void)OnSyncComplete:%@ message=%@",result, message);
    //jxxtodo: Ensure all existing objects are reset, including DB and network connections
    if (0 == [result intValue]){
        NSString *strMsg = [ErrorHandler getErrorTextByErrorNumber:SYNC_SUCCESS_INF withObjects:nil];
        [self logEvent:strMsg];
    }else if (2 == [result intValue]){//no sync required
        NSString *strMsg = [ErrorHandler getErrorTextByErrorNumber:NO_NEED_SYNC_INF withObjects:nil];
        [self logEvent:strMsg];
    }else if (3 == [result intValue]) {
        NSString *strMsg = [ErrorHandler getErrorTextByErrorNumber:SYNC_RESET_EMPTY_INF withObjects:nil];
        [self logEvent:strMsg];
    } else{
        NSString *strMsg = [ErrorHandler getErrorTextByErrorNumber:SYNC_COMMON_ERR withObjects:nil];
        [self logEvent:strMsg];

        return;
    }
    [m_pSyncController release];
    m_pSyncController = nil;
    self.m_backupSet = nil;
    [self performSelector:@selector(startBackgroundBackupActivity) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}
```

Right now, `OnSyncComplete:message:` is what calls `startBackupActcitivy` from within the `BackgroundBackupHandler` class.

I have another class `LocationHandler` which checks the flag sent from the server and does something based on the flag. So if the flag is set to backup then wipe, it will run a backup then wipe the device.

How would I call `OnSyncComplete:message:` from the `LocationHandler` class.

Ive tried:

```
BackgroundBackupHandler *bgBackup = [[BackgroundBackupHandler alloc]init];
[bgBackup OnSyncComplete:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] message:nil];
```

This is giving me errors and terminating my application. Is there anyway to call `startBackgroundBackupActivity` from the `LocationHandlerClass`.

The error is that the application crashed and aborts. NSInvalidArgumentException, where nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext.
The locationHandler will start a background task, which will then sync the device and return control to the OnSyncComplete method in the LocationHandler class which then in turn calls the OnSyncComplete in the BackgroundBackupHandler class.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Larme i have updated question above.

Comment: You declare a method `OnSyncComplete:message:` but you invoke `onSyncComplete:message:` (different case). In Objective-C, method names should be `lowerCamelCase`. You should also avoid using `get` in a method name as it usually implies that the caller must provide a buffer.

Answer (score -1):

The 2 ways to create communication between object are:
1) delegations
2) notifications

In your case it seems like the notification can work better.
Check this out